# How to disable automatic layout for a JavaFX Group?

Tags: javafx-2

I have a Group whose coordinate transformations I want to manage completely myself. The built-in `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties are messing this up, and I would like to disable them completely.

There seems to be at least two ways of doing this. `relocate(0,0)` or simply setting the properties to 0. But doing this in the `Group` construction is too early; the values are 0 there anyways.

So: how do I tell the `Group` to not bother doing layouting?

Naturally, I can also leave the layoutX|Y as they are, and compensate for them in my own transforms. That's the plan B.

Ref. [JavaFX Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is a bit hard to understand, but I'm guessing you have a [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) in a managed layout [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) of some kind (such as a [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) or [VBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html)) but you don't want the Group's layout values being set by the layout pane -- in which case you can make the group [unmanaged](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setManaged%28boolean%29).

For example, in the following code, the unmanaged nature of the group causes it to have layout co-ordinates of 0,0 rather than layout co-ordinates of 50,60 which StackPane would usually set to center it inside the parent StackPane.

```
Group group = new Group(new Rectangle(100, 80));
group.setManaged(false);
StackPane container = new StackPane();
container.setMinSize(StackPane.USE_PREF_SIZE, StackPane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
container.setPrefSize(200, 200);
container.setMaxSize(StackPane.USE_PREF_SIZE, StackPane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
container.getChildren().add(group);
```

Comment: Spot on! I have a Group within a StackPane. Thanks for mentioning .setManaged. :) One more time that shows how SO rocks!!

Comment: @jewelsea, I am wondering how you assign a Rectangle object to a Group variable. Is that a typo?

Comment: @Urs, Yes, it was a typo.  I edited the answer to fix it.  Thanks for pointing it out.